# TensorBoard UncaughtTypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: python, tensorflow, gensim, tensorboard

I have trained a `gensim` Doc2Vec model on five million documents, and those documents are tagged with a unique ID (IDNO). Now I am loading the model, and accessing a specific subset of the vectors based on IDNO. First, I load a `pandas` df from a database and it looks like this:

```
IDNO    author   document
123XYZ  john     the cat sat
234FGH  jane     the dog ran
345RTY  jane     the hippo ate
```

Then I load the model:

```
model = Doc2Vec.load('documents_doc2vec_vectorsize100_mincount2_epochs50.model')
```

Then I access the three vectors that are in my df:

```
row_id_list = list(df.row_id)
vectors_tuple = itemgetter(*row_id_list)(model.docvecs)
embedding = np.asarray(vectors_tuple)
```

Then I create all the necessary `TensorBoard` files:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

X = tf.Variable([0.0], name='embedding')
place = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=embedding.shape)
set_x = tf.assign(X, place, validate_shape=False)

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(set_x, feed_dict={place: embedding})

summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('log', sess.graph)

config = projector.ProjectorConfig()
embedding_conf = config.embeddings.add()
embedding_conf.tensor_name = 'embedding:0'
embedding_conf.metadata_path = os.path.join('metadata','metadata.tsv')
projector.visualize_embeddings(summary_writer, config)

saver = tf.train.Saver([X])
saver.save(sess, os.path.join('log', 'model1.ckpt'), 1)
```

When I run `tensorboard --logdir=log`, `TensorBoard` loads, but it says points and dimensions are loading. When I enter Chrome Developer Tools, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at (index):147401
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at (index):147399
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload ((index):143698)
```

I had `TensorBoard` working before, but that was when I set `embedding` to `model.docvecs.vectors_docs` rather than accessing specific vectors and pushing them into a `numpy` array.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

You defined embedding vector as 1-d tensor with float zero inside:

```
X = tf.Variable([0.0], name='embedding')
```

According to [this manual](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/get_started/embedding_viz) it should be 2-d tensor with [Number_of_vectors, Dimensions_in_vector] shape, i.e:

```
embedding_var = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100,10]), name='embedding')
```

Considering Chrome Dev Tools error:
TensorBoard requests `/info?run=[run_id]` to obtain JSON data with embeddings variables. In your case, back-end fails to determine `tensorShape` and returns `tensorName` only. Front-end tries to read `tensorShape` to assess its `length` property. On this step JS raises `Uncaught TypeError` since `tenshorShape` is not defined. It's a bug of tensorboard`s back-end.

Comment: In my case I have a 2D array passed in as feature but still getting the same error